# How to call tearDown() with Throughput Shaping Timer

Tags: java, jmeter, junit4, jmeter-plugins, teardown

I have JMeter test plan which tests REST API. During execution, it posts items to DB (POST), and next steps are other operations, like GET, UPDATE, DELETE.

When the load is high, and service can't process all requests some items are presented at DB after test execution.

I tried to collect all successfully created to [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). And delete all after the load is done at `tearDown()` method.

For load testing [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) is used. The test plan is executed in not GUI mode, and the load is specified with `load_profile` property.

The main problem is Shaping timer stops execution after set time. Thus `tearDown()` has never been executed:

[image]

***How to execute `tearDown()` after main load part with Shaping timer?***

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug (or expected behavior) of the Throughput Shaping Timer plugin, I would recommend clarifying this in the [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)

In the meantime you can use the [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) to set desired "Minion Load" Thread Group duration and "normal" [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to limit JMeter's throughput to the desired value.

Comment: I want to run method after `Throughput Shaping Timer` finish load execution.